# Android Studio Дизайнер неправильно отображает элементы

Tags: android-studio

Дизайнер xml файлов при добавлении любого элемента отображает его всегда в левом верхнем углу. При этом при запуске приложения на устройстве всё отображается нормально. То есть не слева сверху, а так, как написано в коде. ConstrainLayout настроен. Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Здесь пока ничего нет"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.834" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

В чём проблема?

Comment: не могли бы вы пожалуйста прикрепить скриншот для лучшей наглядности?

Comment: Уже не могу. Я ничего не понял, он просто перестал так делать.

Comment: ну вообще в дизайнере могут быть глюки порой, он относительно недавно стал более-менее нормально работать